# attempt to creat a new directory in Downloads finishes to creating a new "~" in the cwd

Tags: python, path, cwd

So I am working on a script for myself in python to download works from Ao3.
I have this setup file

```
{
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "downloadsPath": "~/Downloads/ao3",
    "format": "epub"
}
```

my problem is with the download path variable.
in my scrip I do the following:

```
def main():
    setup = openJson(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "setup.json"))
    os.makedirs(setup["downloadsPath"], exist_ok=True)
```

to make sure the destination for downloads exists.
except that rather than creating the ao3 folder in `/home/user/Downloads/`
it creates a new `~/` folder in the CWD so something like `/cwd/~/Downloads/ao3`

I have no idea why it started doing this because before I started to do the rest of the script everything was fine but after a day of working on the script this behaviour started.

Comment: It appears that `makedirs()` simply doesn't consider a folder named `~` to be anything special — so you will need to translate it yourself with [`os.path.expanduser()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser).

Comment: Thank you is works now. i ended up doing composing `expanduser` and `expandenv`. could you post your comment as an answer so i can flag it as the solution?

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for the offer. I've never heard of `expandenv`, perhaps you meant `expandvars`.

Comment: yea sorry it's `expendvars`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in a comment, `makedirs()` doesn't automatically handle expansion of a folder named `~` to the user’s home directory, however you can easily do it yourself via [`os.path.expanduser()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) as illustrated below:

```
import os

setup = {
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password",
    "downloadsPath": "~/Downloads/ao3",
    "format": "epub"
}

downloadsPath = os.path.expanduser(setup["downloadsPath"])
print(downloadsPath)
os.makedirs(downloadsPath, exist_ok=True)
```

You can also do something similar using the object-oriented [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module (which I highly recommend learning and using):

```
from pathlib import Path

downloadsPath = Path(setup["downloadsPath"]).expanduser()
print(downloadsPath)
downloadsPath.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```